# Air: Possible? Writing into installed application package

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, gumbo

This is probably a bad idea or whatever you wan't to call it. Nevertheless, curious to know if Air can write inside it's own installed package. I'm referring to the OSX '.app' files found in great numbers in the applications folder. Since every one of these can be opened as a regular folder, i'm guessing that's what they are.

What other fancy filewriting tricks am i missing out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a bad idea.  That said, it looks like it's probably possible.  Something like (untested):

```
var appDir:File = File.applicationDirectory; // uses app: URI, can't be written to
var appPath:String = appDir.nativePath;
var writeableAppDir:File = new File(appPath);

var newFile:File = writeableAppDir.resolvePath("writeme.txt");
```

The [`nativePath`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html#nativePath) and [`applicationDirectory`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory) documentation in the `File` class are full of warnings against this.  Follow them.

From the docs:

> Modifying content in the application
>   directory is a bad practice, for
>   security reasons. If you want to store
>   application-specific data, consider
>   using the application storage
>   directory
>   (File.applicationStorageDirectory). If
>   you want any of the content in the
>   application storage directory to have
>   access to the application-priveleged
>   functionality (AIR APIs), you can
>   expose that functionality by using a
>   sandbox bridge.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I was concidering writing directly into the app to enable a user to modify the application configuration and redistributing the app.
Shame on me for not believing the docs without bugging you guys.